# cat <(echo 'hello') can run, but can't run in shell script mode

Tags: bash, shell

If I run `cat <(echo 'hello')` in the [root@hostname]#, it shows correctly

But if I turn the above into below script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <(echo 'hello')
```

and run sh -x test.sh, it get back to me below errors:

```
./test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.sh: line 3: `cat <(echo 'hello')'
```

Reason ask this is because I follow this [thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274330/check-ip-is-in-range-of-whitelist-array/274343#274343?newreg=04ddf5957eef40a983823efc3f7b8292)(the green answer one), it prompt the same error.

Comment: The POSIX bourne shell `sh` does not support process-substitution(`<()`), you need to use boune-again shell `bash` to support it.

Comment: By all means if you have `bash` installed (check by doing `which bash` or `echo $SHELL`). Change the first line to `#!/bin/bash` and try running the same script as `bash -x test.sh`

Comment: if you really need to use `#!/bin/sh` then you'll have to extend your Q to a real use case, as `cat <(echo hello)` doesn't make much sense. why not just `echo hello` or assuming you're thinking about one process feeding another, the use a pipeline, i.e. `echo $RANDOM \* 5 | bc` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you @Inian, tried, that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using Bash-specific syntax in your script, so you should change the shebang line to something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and if you want to invoke the program like you were doing you should run:

```
bash -x test.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much @David, it works after switch to bash